# Global service registration and comma operator

Tags: c++, global-variables, registration, void, comma-operator

There is a global function that registers services:

```
// services call this to register upon creation
extern void RegisterService(adapter::Service *s);
```

Then somewhere in a .cpp file some service registers itself:

```
// create the adapter and register with libecap to reach the host application
static const bool Registered = (libecap::RegisterService(new Adapter::Service), true);
```

Why registration isn't made simply by calling libecap::RegisterService(new Adapter::Service)?
It looks even stranger, because the global variable ***Registered*** isn't used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you can't place expressions in empty space floating around in a source file. Only *declarations*.

This is a common way to force an expression to be evaluated here, even if the resulting object is never actually used afterwards.

Comment: "empty space floating around in a source file" -- Isn't it also called *global namespace*?

Answer (score 3):

The aithor of the code wanted to have a bool flag that will say whether the service already registered. He could write for example

```
libecap::RegisterService(new Adapter::Service);
static const bool Registered =  true;
```

provided that Registered is a local variable.

But if Registered is not a local variable then he may not call a function outside some other function (or main). So the only method to define a global bool variable (with external or internal linkage) and at the same time to call a function that has return type void is the following

```
static const bool Registered = (libecap::RegisterService(new Adapter::Service), true);
```

The result of the expression of the comma operator is true an Registered will be initialized by this value. And at the same time function libecap::RegisterService(new Adapter::Service) will be called.

As an alternative he could define a class the constructor of which would contain the call of the function and the destructor would contain some unregister stuff.

Comment: "He could write for example: `libecap::RegisterService(new Adapter::Service);`" No, he couldn't.

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit Why not?

Comment: Only declarations may be found at namespace scope. That is a function call.